# Starting up a Bluetooth server

Tags: c++, bluetooth

I implemented the Bluetooth server according to the example shown in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252882/Bluetooth-Server-Programming-on-Windows.
I modified it a bit to use AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM.
It works fine.
However, if I restart the computer, the program hangs at accept().
If I then un-pair the two devices and then re-pair them again, the program works.
Any clues as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

So the program hangs on accept, from what I know accept in windows bluetooth sockets and other Bluetooth sockets platforms, accept like functions are a blocking asynchronous call, it pretty much block/freezes the **thread** that is on, and waits a client to connect, now winsock2 handles one thread operations much better than other platforms yes i'm looking to you android ,but still the program might get unstable if two of those calls occur , furthermore the guy only checks for one error in accept , so try referring to this complete list of [winsock errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx)
 (retrieved by `winsockgetlasterror()`)  ,

also can you pls provide the client code and more info like on what platform, ide,devices  , you are using ?